# VPS/VDS for Continuous Integration (TeamCity)

Tags: continuous-integration, hosting, virtualization, teamcity

We are looking at moving some of existing infrastructure to the virtual space, hence the question:

Would you recommend a virtual hosting provider for hosting TeamCity CI server, based on your experience?

It'd be nice to get company names/links but if that's against the rules listing your VPS configuration should also do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this answer on JetBrains forum http://www.jetbrains.net/devnet/message/5258265#5258265 these are the recommended specs for CI box:

> Based on our experience, a modest hardware like 3.2 dual core CPU, 3.2Gb memory under Windows, 1Gb network adapter can provide acceptable performance for the setup

I don't think that VPS market has anything to offer in that space with acceptable price tag.